# main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `tree::tree()'

Tags: c++

**C++ TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64-bit

Error: main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `tree::tree()'**

*main.cpp*

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    tree tree1;
    return 0;
}
```

*tree.h*

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H
using namespace std;

class tree{
    public:
        tree();

};

#endif
```

*tree.cpp*

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

tree::tree(){
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

Comment: How do you compile your code? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268483/main-cpp-text0x5f-undefined-reference-to?rq=1 for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a terminal, compile your code like this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp tree.cpp
```

Execute your program, like this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./main 
Hello
```

Please read about linking in [Linking files in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532400/linking-files-in-g).

---

By the way, I changed your code to first include the standard library `iostream` and then your header file, so now the code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tree.h"
```

That way, I got rid of this warning:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./tree.h:3:17: warning: using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace
      'std'
using namespace std;
                ^
1 warning generated.
```

If you want, you can read more in [Ordering of using namespace std; and includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841130/ordering-of-using-namespace-std-and-includes), but I think this is *advanced* for you right now.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @JanHank Sorry since this is not my answer, but you do not *execute* C++ or C code, you compile it and execute the resulting binary file. You use the term *execute* w.r.t code that runs inn an interpreter such as JavaScript, but I'm afraid that with partial compilation that's not quite true either. Regardless, never say *execute C++ code*.